# Copy Image to images directory in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am developing a WPF application. I am letting user to select some picture and after that i want to save that image in `EmployeePics` directory which is in same Project directoy.
Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I have written following code but its not working:

```
string appPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EmployeePics\\");
File.Copy(Chosen_File, appPath + Chosen_File);
```

I am getting following exception:
[image]

Comment: Have you IO permission? What's in the strings `Chosen_File` and `appPath`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method. If it is not impossible, please, provide more details.

**Update:**

To resolve pictures directory you could use `System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EmployeePics")`.

**Update 2**

Full code:

`File.Copy(Chosen_File, Path.Combine(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EmployeePics"), Path.GetFileName(Chosen_File)))`.

Comment: This will get the location of the exe so then you just have to append the path. Link: www.csharp-examples.net/get-application-directory/

Comment: Use `Path.Combine` instead of `appPath + Chosen_File`. Are you really use WPF, not WinForms?

Comment: @JohnKZ Yes this is WPF application.

Comment: @JohnKZ the following line is not working either: `File.Copy(Chosen_File, System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EmployeePics")+Chosen_File);`

Comment: How about this?  `File.Copy(Chosen_File, System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EmployeePics", Chosen_File))`

Comment: Yes, Nida, try this. But if `Chosen_File` is full path you should extract file name from it.

Comment: @Nida Sulheri: I have updated my answer. Does this solution work?

Comment: @JohnKZ I tried the following line. No exception occurred but did not move the file to EmployeePics folder :( `File.Copy(Chosen_File, Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EmployeePics"+Path.GetFileName(Chosen_File)));`

Comment: @JohnKZ and this line is not valid because there is no Path.Combine method which takes 3 parameters: `File.Copy(Chosen_File, System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EmployeePics", Chosen_File));`

Comment: @Nida Sulheri: You are right. You should use `Path.Combine` twice: `File.Copy(Chosen_File, Path.Combine(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EmployeePics"), Path.GetFileName(Chosen_File)))`.

Comment: @Nida Sulheri: Could you provide value for Chosen_File and stack trace?